# Multiple linear regression using binary, non-binary variables

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm hoping to obtain some feedback on the most appropriate method in undertaking this approach. I have a `df` that contains revenue data and various related variables. I'm hoping to determine which variables predict revenue. These variables are both binary and non-binary though

I'll display an example `df` below and talk through my thinking:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Date' :    ['01/01/18','01/01/18','01/01/18','01/01/18','02/01/18','02/01/18','02/01/18','02/01/18'],
    'Country' :    ['US','US','US','MX','US','US','MX','MX'],
    'State' :    ['CA','AZ','FL','BC','CA','CA','BC','BC'],
    'Town' :    ['LA','PO','MI','TJ','LA','SF','EN','TJ'],    
    'Occurences' :    [1,5,3,4,2,5,10,2],   
    'Time Started' :    ['12:03:00 PM','02:17:00 AM','13:20:00 PM','01:25:00 AM','08:30:00 AM','12:31:00 AM','08:35:00 AM','02:45:00 AM'],    
    'Medium' :    [1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2],    
    'Revenue' :    [100000,40000,500000,8000,10000,300000,80000,1000],                  
 })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Out:

```
       Date Country State Town  Occurences     Time      Medium  Revenue
0  01/01/18      US    CA   LA           1  12:03:00 PM       1   100000
1  01/01/18      US    AZ   PO          10  02:17:00 AM       2    40000
2  01/01/18      US    FL   MI           3  13:20:00 PM       1   500000
3  01/01/18      MX    BC   TJ           4  01:25:00 AM       2     8000
4  02/01/18      US    CA   LA           2  08:30:00 AM       1    10000
5  02/01/18      US    CA   SF           5  12:31:00 AM       1   300000
6  02/01/18      MX    BC   EN          10  08:35:00 AM       1    80000
7  02/01/18      MX    BC   TJ           2  02:45:00 AM      2     1000
```

So the specific variables that influence revenue are `Medium`, `Time Started`, and `Occurrences`. I also have location groups that can be used, such as, `Country`, `State`, and `Town`.

Would a multiple linear regression be appropriate here? Should I standardise the independent variables somehow? `Medium` will always be either `1` or `2`. But should I group `Time Started` and `Occurrences`? Times will fall between a 20hr period `(8AM - 4AM)`, while occurrences will fall between `1-10`. Should these variable be assigned to dummy variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas: you could apply a [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) transform of Medium, subtract the earliest starting time from all Time values, and convert it to hours. Then [standardize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) all three variable in some way, and follow-up with multiple linear regression.

Before going into that kind of complex model, you could try plotting each variable against revenue and against each other, and see if there's any interesting patterns.

Comment: Thanks @foxpal. `Medium` will either be `1` or `2` so that seems to be easy. I could maybe standardise `Time` into groups as well. Something like `8AM - 6PM` as `1`. `6PM - 12PM` as `2` and `12AM - 4AM` as `3`. I'm with you on the multiple linear regression.